# Shared connection to host closed

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, amazon

I launched 2 Ubuntu servers in AWS. Ansible installed on one server and also done `ssh keygen` to connect to another remote server (2). Whenever I'm trying to ping the server through Ansible (command: `ansible servername -m ping`). I am getting an error that the connection to the host was closed and `/usr/bin/python` not found.

This is the error message:

```
172.XX.XX.XXX | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.XX.XX.XXX closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 0
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which of the two systems produced the error message since I'm unfamiliar with Ansible but I would think it's the remote system. Can you log into it through other means, e. g. SSH, to run the commands `ls -l /usr/bin/python` and `which python` and then [edit] your question to include the command output? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when configure digital ocean on Ubuntu 18.04 VM

I set in your local ansible inventory file the python3 interpreter

```
[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter = /usr/bin/python3
```

after that all worked fine.